# Unable to create indexes or communicate with AWS Open search using spring boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to integrate AWS elastic search (Open search) with my spring boot application. For this, I followed the tutorial at https://medium.com/@prasanth_rajendran/how-to-integrate-spring-boot-elasticsearch-data-with-aws-445e6fc72998 with slight changes.

The error that I am getting is **Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required**  and I am not able to fix it.

Here are the code snippets from my application

The dependencies I used

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.244</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the parent pom dependency

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

The application.yml looks like this

```
server:
port: 8087

spring:
  application:
  name: AWS ELK Demo

management:
  health:
  elasticsearch:
   enabled: false

cloud:
  aws:
  credentials:
    access-key: my-access-key
    secret-key: my-secret key
region:
  static: eu-central-1
```

Configuration class for Rest High-Level Client

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.awselkdemo.repository")
public class ElasticSearchRestClientConfiguration  {
  
  @Bean
  public RestHighLevelClient client() {
    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myuser", "myuser-password")
    );

    RestClientBuilder builder = 
       RestClient.builder(httpHost()).setHttpClientConfigCallback(
            httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    );

    return new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
  }

  @Bean
  public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
  }

  private HttpHost httpHost() {
    return new HttpHost(
            "search-my-test-cluster-jashsah67ashas.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com",
            443,
            "https"
    );
   }
 }
```

And the exception I get is

```
2022-06-22 09:40:07.726  INFO 1299 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-22 09:40:07.739  INFO 1299 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-22 09:40:07.757 ERROR 1299 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'photoRepository' defined in com.bosch.awselkdemo.repository.PhotoRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticSearchRestClientConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:934) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.bosch.awselkdemo.AwsElkDemoApplication.main(AwsElkDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:543) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required; nested exception is ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:601) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.doExists(RestIndexTemplate.java:106) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractIndexTemplate.exists(AbstractIndexTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:87) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2701) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2154) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:1279) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(RestIndexTemplate.java:106) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:582) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Hitting the domain endpoint at AWS gives me this information

```
{
"name": "5a8d2c313919cc9hjh3287ehje872",
"cluster_name": "3873287387:my-test-cluster",
"cluster_uuid": "shas_asjasihhjdjhq",
"version": {
"distribution": "opensearch",
"number": "1.2.4",
"build_type": "tar",
"build_hash": "unknown",
"build_date": "2022-04-18T07:00:42.948341Z",
"build_snapshot": false,
"lucene_version": "8.10.1",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
},
"tagline": "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}
```

Looking forward to some suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately Spring Data Elasticsearch is not compatible with AWS OpenSearch at this time.

Answer (score 5):

i had problems exactly like you. And i replace all my org.elasticsearch lib with new lib from org.opensearch then it worked!

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensearch.client/opensearch-rest-high-level-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

You can read **Migrating to the OpenSearch Java high-level REST client** for more information.
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/java-rest-high-level/